# How does this for comprehension build state while assigning to underscore?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, for-comprehension

**Background**
The val `forExpression` (below) returns a `StateT` monad which takes as a parameter an initial state, adds 2 and then 3 to the state and then multiplies this by 10.

**Question**
 Why are the `add(2)` and `add(3)` functions executed when this `StateT` instance is run after these two functions appear to have their result "thrown away" by assigning it to the underscore?

**Example**
 if you evaluate `forExpression` with a beginning state of `IntState(1)`, why does it return `IntState(60)` instead of `IntState(10)`?

There is a minimal code snippet below or you can view the full source [on github](https://github.com/alvinj/FPMonadTransformers/blob/master/src/main/scala/v1_hard_coded_for/StateTHardCodedForExpression.scala).

This code was encountered while reading Alvin Alexander's "Functional Programming Simplified".

```
  case class IntState(i: Int)

  def add(i: Int) = StateT[IO, IntState, Int] { oldState =>
    val newValue = i + oldState.i
    val newState = oldState.copy(i = newValue)
    IO((newState, newValue))
  }

  def multiply(i: Int) = StateT[IO, IntState, Int] { oldState =>
    val newValue = i * oldState.i
    val newState = oldState.copy(i = newValue)
    IO((newState, newValue))
  }

  val forExpression: StateT[IO, IntState, Int] = for {
    _ <- add(2)
    _ <- add(3)
    x <- multiply(10)
  } yield x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple high-level explanation: `StateT` calculations have separate state and result (e.g. `newState` and `newValue` in `IO((newState, newValue))` in your code). What appears to the left of `<-` is the `newValue` part, and only it is ignored in `_ <- ...`. The manipulation of `newState` is implicit, and it isn't thrown away.

For low-level, you can:

1. Translate the for-comprehension into `flatMap`.
2. Expand the definition of `StateT`'s `flatMap`.
3. See what happens with state in the result function.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Will translate the for-comprehension into flatMap and see if that helps!